# Output and Input format are giving differences between machines

Tags: c++, input, output

My problem is with I/O in C++, and I'm getting two very different outputs from different machines. My machine gives out the correct answer, while the other doesn't. Why would that happen? compiler differences? How do I fix it? Is this about lack of good programming habits?

For my program, each test case consists of one or more project sheets. A project sheet consists of a line containing the project name in capital letters, followed by the userids of students, one per line. I am supposed to print the name of each project, followed by the number of students in it. I also have to count repeating students only once in the same project, and remove students that signed for more than one projects altogether.

My program output is printing extra undesired '\n' at the end of project names. Also, the stop conditions "1" and "0" started being saved into my project vector for some reason and counted as students. But the weird thing is that only happens in the other machine.

Here's my code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct student {
    string userID;
    int projectSigned;
};

bool operator == (const student& a, const student& b) {
    return a.userID == b.userID;
}

bool operator < (const student& a, const student& b) {
    return a.userID < b.userID;
}

struct project {
    string name;
    int numStudents;
};

bool operator < (const project& a, const project& b) {
    if (a.numStudents != b.numStudents) {
        return a.numStudents > b.numStudents;
    } else {
        return a.name < b.name;
    }
}

project criarProjeto(const string& nameProj) {
    project proj; 
    proj.name = nameProj;
    proj.numStudents = 0;
    return proj;
}

student createStudent(const string& ID, const int& projectNumber) {
    student newStudent;
    newStudent.userID = ID;
    newStudent.projectSigned = projectNumber;
    return newStudent;
}

int main () {
    string newLine;
    do {
        vector<student> vecStudents; 
        vector<project> vecProj;
        getline(cin, newLine);
        while(newLine != "1" && newLine != "0") {
            bool isName = isupper(newLine[0]);
            if (isName) {
                project newProj = criarProjeto(newLine);
                vecProj.push_back(newProj);
            } 
            else {
                student newStudent = createStudent(newLine, vecProj.size() - 1);
                auto lower = lower_bound(vecStudents.begin(), vecStudents.end(), newStudent);
                const bool found = lower != vecStudents.end() && *lower == newStudent;
                if (!found) {
                    vecStudents.push_back(newStudent);
                    sort(vecStudents.begin(), vecStudents.end());
                    vecProj.back().numStudents++;
                } else {
                    auto idx = lower - vecStudents.begin();
                    if (vecStudents[idx].projectSigned != -1 && vecProj.size() != 1 + (unsigned long)vecStudents[idx].projectSigned) {
                        vecProj[vecStudents[idx].projectSigned].numStudents--;
                        vecStudents[idx].projectSigned = -1;
                    }

                }
            }

            getline(cin, newLine);
        }
        
        sort(vecProj.begin(), vecProj.end());
        for (unsigned long j = 0; j < vecProj.size(); j++) {
            cout << vecProj[j].name << " " << vecProj[j].numStudents << endl;
        }

    } while (newLine != "0");
}
```

Given Input:

```
UBQTS TXT
tthumb
LIVESPACE BLOGJAM
philton
aeinstein
YOUBOOK
j97lee
sswxyzy
j97lee
aeinstein
SKINUX
1
0
```

Correct output (gcc 12.2.0 running on MacOS 12.6.3 given input typed by hand):

```
YOUBOOK 2
LIVESPACE BLOGJAM 1
UBQTS TXT 1
SKINUX 0
```

The other machine's output (gcc 9.3.0 running on Ubuntu 20.04 on the cloud and automating input write):

```
YOUBOOK
 2
LIVESPACE BLOGJAM
 1
SKINUX
 1
UBQTS TXT
 1
```

I tried manually and via erase() removing the '\n' from the end of newLine but it either didn't work or gave me errors. I tried using pop_back() when printing outputs and while it does correct the output format problems, it didn't correct the stop conditions "1" and "0" being saved into my vector and printed out.

Edit: After printing each character for each received input, I found out my machine doesn't obtain character 13 (carriage return) at the end of inputs, while the other does.

Edit2: After talking to the cloud's admins, it appears a Windows-type file (one with CRLF instead of LF line endings) was submitted as the input test cases. Because of that, the machine which was running Ubuntu added the CR character to the end of lines, which made my program not function. This'll be resolved by the admins.

Thank you very much for all the help and reading.

Comment: `getline(cin, newLine);` -- What is the input?

Comment: You asked the identical question previously (seems to now be deleted). You should engage with the people giving you advice.

Comment: And I'll say it again, you cannot remove the newline from the end of `newLine` because there is no newline there. [getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) does not add the newline it reads to the string it returns.

Comment: @john I realized the "binary_search" error was on me. After correcting it, because it changed so much of the answer's context, I decided to simply redo the question.

Comment: `vector<student> userIDs;` -- This is a vector of students, not ID's.  Naming variables appropriately makes the code easier to understand.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie updated with input information.

Comment: *compiler differences?* -- You didn't state what compilers are used on each machine, version of the compiler used on each machine, the operating systems on both machines, etc.

Comment: @ArturWeb Your code runs fine for me. How are you supplying the input on the two machines? Even though you are reading from `cin` it seems unlikely that you are typing all the input by hand.

Comment: @ArturWeb Are you supplying the input using a text file?  If so, where did you produce the text file, on Windows or on another operating system?  Whatever it is, are both machines the same operating system you produced the text file on?  Also, `cout << vecProj[j].name << " " << vecProj[j].numStudents << endl;` that is the only line that really matters.  Everything else about `std::sort`, `lower_bound`, etc. is just noise.  Write a simple function that reads the input, sticks a number at the end of the input, and outputs that, line by line.  That is called "divide and conquer" debugging.

Comment: @john Updated with the information I have on both machines. I will update with more information if I can find it.

Comment: @PaulMackenzie doesn’t the input also matters aside from the output? Maybe the problem isn’t on output but on input.

Comment: @ArturWeb *doesn’t the input also matters aside from the output?* -- If you produced that file on a Mac, and the machine running in the cloud is Windows-based, then that is an issue. A text file on Mac is a different format than on Windows, most notably the end-of-line character(s).  The `std::getline` is expecting text data, but a text file is different on both operating systems.  Maybe this is the issue you are running into, and that is basically telling the cloud machine that you are sending a text file as input, when it isn't a text file as far as the cloud's OS is concerned.

Comment: [See this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) and pay close attention to the `Representation` section.  Note that Windows uses two characters to denote the end-of-line, while macOS has a single LF character.  Again, if the machine you produced the text file on was a Mac, and the machine running your program is Windows, then you need to ensure that the text file was translated properly from one OS to the other before using it on the target OS.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I updated the post with the other machine's specs. I am not using any text file on my personal machine. Just typing each line by hand. The other machine is running Ubuntu 20.04 on the cloud and automating the input, but I don't know how. The test cases (input files) are already done in the cloud, I don't have to upload any input files, just the code.

Comment: @ArturWeb Then again, divide and conquer debugging.  As soon as you get the input, output each and every character value in that string.  If you see a stray LF or CR in there, then the issue is a translation one.  The `std::getline` does not leave extraneous end-of-line sequences in the string -- `for (auto c : newLine) { std::cout << (int)c << "\n" }`  -- Something like that is what you should do immediately after getting the input.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It appears the other machine, differently than mine, has character 13 (carriage return) on the end of inputs. Why would that be and how do I fix it? Thanks for all the help.

Comment: You need to contact the admins at your school and have them look at it.  Obviously text files are not being uploaded/sent/received/translated properly over to the cloud machine.  If this were localized, then you would use a translator program to convert the text file to one that is compatible (many text editors have a "save" option that allows this).

Comment: As to a stopgap fix:  `newLine.erase(std::remove_if(newLine.begin(), newLine.end(), isctrl), newLine.end());` after you get the input will remove the control characters.

Comment: @ArturWeb What seems likely is that the text file has Windows line endings, i.e. carriage return then line feed. On a Windows machine those two characters would be translated to a single line feed character on input. But that is not going to happen on Linux. Instead the line feed alone is the line ending, so you are left with lines containing a trailing carriage return character.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thank you for all the help, the issue is solved. I updated the question with more information.

Comment: @ArturWeb -- I'm surprised that others didn't run into the same issue.  In any event, glad it is being looked at by your school admins.